# Iterative algorithm to generate all combinations with any number of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I have a problem that I tried to solve myself but I'm not sure if there is better algorithm to solve this.
Suppose I have a dict with the entire alphabet.
I can invoke the function passing a string of characters indicating the keys related to the lists that I want to use to generate the output. I can add the same key multiple times.
I would like to generate all possible combinations between them and solve it without recursion.

I tried to solve the problem myself using the brute force approach below but I would like to know if there is a better approach to that.

My attempt is as follows:

```
words_dict = {
    2: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    3: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    4: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
    5: ['j', 'k', 'l'],
    6: ['m', 'n', 'o'],
    7: ['p', 'q', 'r'],
    8: ['t', 'u', 'v', 'w'],
    9: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
}


def generate_combinations(numbers):
    words_to_expand = words_dict[int(numbers[0])]
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        letters_list = words_dict[int(numbers[i])]
        aux_words_expanded = []
        for incomplete_word in words_to_expand:
            for letter_to_combine in letters_list:
                expanded_word = incomplete_word + letter_to_combine
                aux_words_expanded.append(expanded_word)
            words_to_expand = aux_words_expanded

    print(words_to_expand)
    return words_to_expand
    pass


generate_combinations('234')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more Pythonic way to do that

```
import itertools
my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
itertools.combinations(my_list) #returns generator of combinations
itertools.permutations(my_list, 3) #same but with length of results specified
```

Answer (score 0):

@MmBaguette's answer points you in the right direction.
It suggests the use of [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

The complete function would be something like:

```
def generate_combinations(numbers):
    words = []
    indexes = (int(val) for val in numbers)
    letter_groups = [words_dict[idx] for idx in indexes]
    for entry in itertools.product(*letter_groups):
        words.append("".join(entry))
    print(words)
    print(len(words))
```

or even shorter:

```
def generate_combinations(numbers):
    indexes = (int(val) for val in numbers)
    letter_groups = [words_dict[idx] for idx in indexes]
    words = list("".join(entry)
        for entry in itertools.product(*letter_groups))
    print(words)
    print(len(words))
```